# Reading CSV file content in SharePoint 2013 Office 365

Tags: 2013, office-365

I have a requirement to read the content from a CSV file which will be uploaded frequently to a document library located in SharePoint 2013 Office 365.

Also, after reading the content I need to populate the CSV file content in to SharePoint list which will also be located in Office 365.

Please suggest me some approach, preferably some technical blog links with sample code.

I have only Windows 8 and Visual Studio 2012 Professional edition installed on my box.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to create a Remote Event Receiver for O365. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/steve_fox/archive/2013/02/03/setting-up-your-development-environment-for-o365-amp-azure-development.aspx) link shows that the requirements for developing a Provider-hosted app are:

1. An O365 Development site
2. An Azure account
3. Visual Studio 2012 or 2013

Also, I wouldn't say that Auto-hosted apps are no longer supported, but rather the preview period has ended for them.  Microsoft [intends to bring them back](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/08/update-autohosted-apps-preview-program-part-2/) by the end of the year (most likely on a paid program).

Answer (score 1):

For provider hosted apps, you don't need sharepoint installed. For a remote event receiver, you will need to create:

1. sharepoint app - this is essentially a small blob of xml that gets added to O365. For a remote event handler, this xml will have info on the specific event to listed for (itemadding for Annoucement lists, for example), and a url of a wcf service to call when the event occurs. Again, this xml (and an icon for the app) gets deployed to the office 365 sharepoint site.
2. The remote hosted app - this is an asp.net site (or a php site, or ...). This site can run on your own iis server, or you could choose to run it in azure. This site will have a wcf service that is called by SharePoint when the given event occurs. The server that this iis site is on does not need sharepoint installed at all. Though, since you will use the SharePoint CSOM,the client libraries will be referenced by the asp.net application, but those are just a couple dlls and they don't require any sort of install process.

In addition to the above, your iis site will need to be configured for SSL. (So, you need certs for SSL. The docs may mention needing server certs for full trust apps, but that doesn't apply to you since you're using O365. Full trust apps only apply when you're using SharePoint on-prem (not O365) and the remote hosted app is also running on your own hardware.)

Comment: Hi @Mike can you please provide some blog reference to start with the approach.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. All MS documentation and examples that I've found are all based on Azure. The same procedure works and is supported by MS, but we are left on our own how to deal with specific IIS issues, for example. But here's a link to an MS doc that creates a remote event receiver: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220051%28v=office.15%29.aspx. Once you have it set up, the deployment steps are identical for any other provider hosted app.